# Retrieving file from Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I know it's been asked, but I have a Python script that generates a file in Heroku. I'm on the Cedar stack, which apparently now allows you to write anywhere within `/app` and not just `/tmp`.

Basically, I run a script and the file that I'm interested in is dropped in `/app`, which if I'm not mistaken is some kind of temporary directory used by my Heroku app. I'll use `/app/test.txt` as an example of the file that's generated by my script that I'm interested in making a link to.

Interestingly, when I do an `ls` within the Python script (through os.subprocess or something similar), I get a directory listing of everything in `/app`, including `requirements.txt, Procfile, /templates/` and so on, including the `test.txt` file I'm interested in.

So, my Python script looks like this:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def my_form_post():
    return render_template("my_form_2.html", filename = "test.txt")
```

and the corresponding template my_form_2.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <body>
        <a href={{filename}}>Right-click to download!</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

The key with that `html href` up above is that I want it to point to a URL, like `my-app.herokuapp.com/app/test.txt`. The HTML above produces the preceding link, which unfortunately isn't valid. Essentially, I'm trying to get the absolute path to the file I create with my Python script. Any ideas on how that can be done?

Before anyone mentions S3, I'm trying to avoid having to use it for now, since it's a file that's small and doesn't need to be transferred to some other servers.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. not at all.

Comment: something like: `send_file(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__), filename)` perhaps.

Comment: Thanks guys. I ended up using Amazon's S3.